# how to add gl transition on video in android with ffmpeg?

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, android-transitions, glsles

GLSL transition on video and render with ffmpeg, but i cannot find proper solution to how to add GLES transition in ffmpeg command.

click here [ffmpeg-gl-transition](https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/ffmpeg-gl-transition)

I already try above solution but it gives errors and not work. Not be understand clearly.
please any one have idea help me.

Comment: @LinsLouis I think you got no Answers because there is no example of your code setup to begin advising from.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ffmpeg-gl-transition](https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/ffmpeg-gl-transition) library. You'll need to use NDK 22.xxxxxx  and ffmpeg 4.4 ( you will have to manually clone/download it).
try to compile it with intel chip systems

For working in android -> use egl methods, remove all non-egl (window) codes.

This will give you the proper results.